# Proof check -- LADR #5A.24 b -- Proving that if matrix A has columns summing to 1, A has an eigenvalue of 1.

Tags: linear-algebra

I was checking my solutions to LADR since I am studying independently, and my solution to 5.A.24B is [different than the other I found online](http://linearalgebras.com/5A.html) (It seems to use some of the same conceptual ideas, but it is a bit mechanistically different.) **Could somebody please check my proof?**

My proof for 24a was identical, so I'm omitting it, but for reference:

Suppose A is an n-by-n matrix with entries in $\mathbf{F}$. Define $T\in \mathscr{L}(\mathbf{F}^n)$ by $Tx = Ax$ where elements of $F^n$ are thought of as n-by-1 column vectors.

(a) (Proven, and I am satisfied with correctness): Suppose the sum of entries in each row of $A$ equals 1. Prove that 1 is an eigenvalue of T.

**(b) (The proof I have written, that I would like evaluated):** Suppose the sum of entries in each column of $A$ equals 1. Prove 1 is an eigenvalue of T.

My approach:

By Thm. 3.114, the matrix of $T' \in \mathscr{L}(\mathbf{F}^{n}{'})$ is $A^T$. By a slight modification to part (a), 1 is an eigenvalue of $A^T$ (with corresponding eigenvector $1 \phi_1 + 1 \phi_2 + ... + 1\phi_n$ in the dual basis).

Thus by Theorem 5.6b, $S' = (T'-1 I)$ is not injective. (I have called this S' since S' must be in the dual space, and so is the dual of some element $S\in \mathscr{L}(\mathbf{F}^n)$.

Since S' is not injective, by Thm. 3.110, S is not surjective.

But the matrix of S is the matrix of S' transpose, so 
matrix of S = $(A^T - 1I)^T = ({A^T}^T - 1I^T) = (A - 1I) $

Thus S = (T - 1I) and S is not surjective.

By Thm. 5.6c, this implies 1 is an eigenvalue of T.

**I am still wrapping my head around the dual space and would like to know if my steps are appropriately justified.**

Comment: This looks fine to me. Where exactly are you unsure of this proof?

Comment: I guess I mostly feel unsure about arbitrarily defining elements in the dual space as dual elements of some element in the regular space, and transitioning so willy-nilly between matrix representation and the name of the transformation?

Comment: Seems OK to me, but the approach feels a bit roundabout. A useful lemma here is that the product of a matrix and a vector is a linear combination of the columns of the matrix, with the coefficients given by the elements of the vector. The proof of your proposition is a then simple corollary or this lemma.

Comment: That lemma is useful in part (a) but gets hairy in part (b) as evidenced by the solution guide I referenced. I generally have a distaste for dealing with vectors componentwise if I can avoid it. Additionally I'd have to define a particular vector, which would be more difficult to define than necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your proof seems fine. You are supposedly concerned about the step where you say "I have called [$T'-1I$] $S'$ since this $S'$ must be an element of the dual space, and so is the dual of some element $S$," however, this is fine because $S'$ has as its matrix representation some matrix $B$ whose transpose is the matrix that represents the transformation $T-1I$, so you are on point.

Comment: Thanks! I was mostly wanting to make sure that I hadn't made up some connection that wasn't there.